# Back propagation algorithm in neural network with shortcut connections

Tags: backpropagation, perceptron, neural-network

I'm currently implementing a multi layer perceptron in F# and I will implement the standard back propagation algorithm, but I'm wondering how the algorithm has to be modified to handle shortcut connections.
With shortcut connections I mean connections that skip layers, for example, connections that connect the input layer directly with the output layer.

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask why you want to do that?

Comment: Because I read that in some situations this kind of network performs well and I thought it was easy to implement. Since the project is a kind of prototipe I will first focus on base features.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no shortcut in your nn, and it is standard feed forward, it means that every input goes through every layer, the same length of path. You can go step by step, layer after layer, and then reverse back and adjust weights. Why I am telling this although you probably know that?

It is because approach to NN with shortcuts will be almost the same...Almost. You will go layer after layer and then back. But BIG DIFFERENCE is THE ONE NEURON exist IN TWO LAYERS.

To be it more complicated, there is surely some difference in order of operations on that one neuron that is parallel in two layers. Both Feed Forward and back propagation.

So answer will not be exact, you need to develop algorithm handling order of computation on layers. 
The simplest solution I can imagine will be just go as usual. Layer after layer (one neuron will be reached more times through on cycle in this algorithm).